# 63: Error: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity

Tags: android, android-studio

When creating a new project i get this error, how do i resolve it?

```
:63: Error: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your XML code You should Start and End within the same entity.  Like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Hello, I am a TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstall android studio, no other methods worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your Error says it clearly

> Error: XML document structures must start and end within the same
>   entity.

In your xml, If you're starting with `<LinearLayout>` then you must have to finish your xml file with `</LinearLayout>` , If `<RelativeLayout>` then `</RelativeLayout>`